# Classification/regression with ground truth splitted between different classes

Tags: regression, machine-learning, classification, supervised-learning, multilabel

I'm currently trying to do **supervised learning with three classes** (let's say A, B and C).
I have a ground-truth which is a bit peculiar, because i have **'membership probabilities/compatibilites' distributed between the three classes** for all data.

For example, the ground truth for a data '1' may be '0.80 A, 0.15 B, 0.05 C'. For a data '2', it can be '0.45 A, 0.1 B, 0.45 C' **(each score is between 0 and 1 and the sum of the three scores is always equal to 1)**.

My problem is that i don't find a way to fully exploit these informations:

- If i do **classification**, my ground truth is transformed to "1 0 0", and it's pretty annoying because for a data with a very balanced ground-truth, almost half of the information is lost.
- If i do (multiple-)**regression** on a 3-dimension vector, i don't take into account the fact that the three results are very correlated (the sum is equal to 1, and the score B cannot be the smallest), as the three prediction will be totally independent.

I have very few data available, so i try to keep the maximum information from them.

I did several researches with the tag 'multi-label' or 'multi-output', but i didn't found anything very relevant.

What's the better way for learning from 'distributed ground-truth' like this ? I'm open to any idea.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use logistic regression. After all the outputs of logistic functions are probablity of data belonging to each class. In a typical problem you have hard assignments, but the logistic regression produces the class probablities which approach the hard assignments. You may need to modify the standard logistic regression algorithm a bit so that you can use probablities instead of hard assignments.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your response. Do you think i could do the same with naive bayes ? Because it's the classifier which produced the best results so far, with hard assignments (logictic regression did pretty good results aswell).

Comment: I think in theory you can use the soft assignments for training any classifiers. For example if you want to train a naive Bayes classifier when calculating the probabilities instead of counting (for a binomial or multinomial event model) you can add the soft assignments.

Comment: Do you know if the Naive Bayes algorithm has to be modified to do that ?
For example, with logistic regression, it appears that the cost function has to be modified to handle training with non-binary classes. Am i wrong ?